# How to use multi-threading to two c++ functions with embedding python?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading

I am learning embedding python in c++ code. I have trouble to use multi-threading to parallelize two c++ functions with embedding python.

My sample codes are shown below:

thread_test.py

```
import time

def test1():
    time.sleep(5) # delays for 5 seconds
    print 1935
    return 'happy'

def test2():
    time.sleep(10) # delays for 10 seconds
    print 3000
```

py_thread.h

```
string test_func1(string file_dir){
    string result_dir;
    string str = "import sys; sys.path.insert(0," "\'"+file_dir+"\'"+")";
    const char * c = str.c_str();
    PyRun_SimpleString (c);

    PyObject * pModule,* pFunc, *pName,  *presult, *pArgs;
    pName = PyString_FromString("thread_test");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    pFunc   = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "test1");
    if(pFunc != NULL) {
        presult=PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,NULL);
        result_dir = PyString_AsString(presult);
    }
    else {
        printf("pFunc returned NULL\n");
    }

    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
    return result_dir;
}

void test_func2(string file_dir){
// Almost the same test_func1 except replacing "test1" with "test2" and no return value of result_dir

}
```

In main class, if I don't use multi-threading and just run the two functions and other normal c++ functions in serious, it works. But if I use some c++ threading techniques, such as OPENMP, it will give me **SEGMENTATION FAULT**. (code is shown below)

main.cpp

```
int main(){
    Py_Initialize();

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {  
        int i = omp_get_thread_num();
        if(i == 0)
        {
            test_func1("../");
        }
        if(i == 1 || omp_get_num_threads() != 2)
        {
             ANOTHER_C++_ONLY_SIMPLE_FUNCTION();
             test_func2("../");
         }

    }
   Py_Finalize();
 return 0;
}
```

I also have tried thread in c++11 and pthread. They all give me segmentation fault. So how can I parallelize the two function???

Thank you!

Comment: python interpreters can only run one python command at a time - they use a lock called the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) to allow multiple threads to take turns executing commands.  So, you can't impose threading from above and have the same interpreter run multiple commands in parallel.

Comment: @TonyD I see the reason from you response. Thank you. So how can I change my current code to achieve my goal? Could you please provide me more details?

Comment: In as much as your goal seems to be to run the python statements in parallel, I don't believe you can - python interpreters are just not designed to support parallel calls like that.  I'm not sure what you'd prefer to do instead - use multiple interpreter instances, or have a mutex contested by test_func1 and test_func2 or have them lock the GIL, but the last two make the outer omp use pointless.  I suggest you google for details about the GIL to understand more of the limitations.